# Syntax similar to except in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My query needs to do the following:

```
  SELECT 
  c1.building,
  c1.room_number 
FROM
  time_slot AS t,
  section AS s,
  classroom AS c1 
WHERE c1.capacity > 30 
  AND s.semester = 'Fall' 
  AND s.year = '2009' 
  AND t.day = 'M' 
  AND t.start_hr < 12 EXCEPT 
  SELECT 
    c1.building,
    c1.room_number 
  FROM
    time_slot AS t,
    section AS s NATURAL 
    JOIN classroom AS c1 
  WHERE c1.capacity > 30 
    AND s.semester = 'Fall' 
    AND s.year = '2009' 
    AND t.day = 'M' 
    AND t.start_hr < 12
```

It has to return all the building names and room numbers from the classroom table that are not occupied on Monday's before noon in the FALL 2009 semester. Changing the where statement is invalid because it gives me a different result.

Comment: How is `time_slot` related to `section` and/or `classroom`?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear.

Comment: classroom (building, room_number, capacity)

    section(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_number, time_slot_id)

    time_slot (time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_min, end_hr, end_min)

Comment: 1. See JOIN. 2. Use explicit JOIN syntax. 3. At which point, everything will become clear

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  c1.building,
  c1.room_number 
FROM
  time_slot AS t,
  section AS s,
  classroom AS c1 
WHERE c1.capacity > 30 
  AND s.semester = 'Fall' 
  AND s.year = '2009' 
  AND t.day = 'M' 
  AND t.start_hr < 12 and ( c1.building,
  c1.room_number ) not in (
  SELECT 
    c1.building,
    c1.room_number 
  FROM
    time_slot AS t,
    section AS s NATURAL 
    JOIN classroom AS c1 
  WHERE c1.capacity > 30 
    AND s.semester = 'Fall' 
    AND s.year = '2009' 
    AND t.day = 'M' 
    AND t.start_hr < 12 )
```